# Replace hyphens with HTML entity for em dash in Vim

Tags: vim

In Vim, I'm trying to run a substitution on this text:

```
lorem ipsum -- dolor sit
```

...to get it to look like this:

```
lorem ipsum&#8212;dolor sit
```

I'm trying to do `:%s/ -- /&#8212;/g`, but it leaves me with this:

```
lorem ipsum -- &#8212;dolor sit
```

How should I adjust my substitution syntax?

Comment: Easy fix--I just needed to escape the ampersand: `:%s/ -- /\&#8212;/g`

Comment: are you not allowed to give yourself an answer (instead of a comment)?

Comment: @morninj your ampersand is not even in your substitution string. Did you forget it in your question?

Comment: @akira Since I'm below a reputation threshold, I have to wait 8 hours before adding an answer.

Comment: @morninj: then now is the time :)

Comment: FYI, [vim-textcov](https://github.com/pydave/textconv.vim) has some functions to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix--I just needed to escape the ampersand: `:%s/ -- /\&#8212;/g`